# Alternatives to JEditorPane & HTMLEditorKit - too slow

Tags: java, html, swing

I'm trying to implement a basic text editor with options for font, bold, italic, underline, and color.  I've used JEditorPane and the associated HTMLEditorKit but when I load a 400K document it takes a full minute to load and most editing takes several seconds.

Comment: you may sadly not get very helpful answers here.  If you dare criticize Java here or any of its API as being slow or badly conceived you'll get a lot of snarky comments and people downvoting you and upvoting the snarky, pointless, comments.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar experience and what I did was to get the JEditorPane to only show a page sized window onto the 400K document (if this is possible in your situation) and then manually deal with scrolling issues.
That way I got a lot of cool functionality from the widget without the massive slowdown (cos the widget only saw part of the text), but I had to write a load of scroll code and keep updating the widget contents as users moved around.

Plus I was doing it so I could view 7G files, which were not going to fit in an memory I had anyway.

Comment: thanks for that feedback.  I had considered it but really wanted to avoid the evil scrolling code.  I'm encouraged, though, that you were able to handle 7GB files. Can you give guidance on how you split the document? Because you can't really split in the middle of a tag (like <b> or <p>).

Comment: The files were log files, so I split on newline.  Not going to work on all types of files I'm afraid.  At least not trivially.

Answer (score 1):

http://java-sl.com/JEditorPanePerformance.html
May be some of the tips could help you to make it a bit faster. I would also recommend to write your own EditorKit based on e.g. StyledEditorKit with all necessary attributes support (see for example http://java-sl.com/editor_kit_tutorial.html).